# Data not getting change in node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular

I am working with Angular, Node and MySQL. I have a simple crud app in which I am adding,updating some data. Whenever I am adding/updating any data I want it to reflect changes in list grid as well.

I am using popups for add/update. So after adding or updating I am calling my generic function which gives me list of data but I was getting response 304 and changes not displayed in grid. So to overcome 304 I have use `app.disable('etag')` in Node.js which gives me status 200. But still changes not displayed, but when I refresh page manually I can see the changes.

Also when I am checking data in network just after performing operation it also holds old values.

Node.js

```
app.post("/addcity", function(req, res) {
    d = req.body;
    var con = mysql.createConnection(connectionString);
    con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        var sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_city(city_name,state_id)  VALUES('" + d.city_name + "'," + d.state_id + ")";
        console.log(sql);
        con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
            if (err)
                throw err;
            res.send(result);
        })
    })
})
```

Angular code

```
PostData(addNewForm: NgForm) {
    var object = {
        "city_name": addNewForm.value.city_name,
        "state_id": addNewForm.value.state_id
    }
    this.service.addCity(object).subscribe();
    this.modalRef.hide();
    this.getAllCities(); // this still gives old values even new City is added in database
}
```

### Update

```
getCities() : Observable<any[]>{
        var details = this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/cities`);
        return forkJoin([details]);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the getAllCities() function, the problem may occur since you are not hitting the server after getting the result

Comment: @TheLawliet94 updated my question getAllCities(). this is hitting api which is giving me list of cities i can see in network tab but with old values. but as i refresh page its gives me latest added city as well

Comment: can u try updating your code to
PostData(addNewForm:NgForm) {
var object = { 
     "city_name":addNewForm.value.city_name,
      "state_id":addNewForm.value.state_id
}
this.service.addCity(object).subscribe((result) => {
    this.modalRef.hide(); 
    this.getAllCities(); 
}, (err) => {
});
}

Comment: Check if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the two requests in async, that's why by the time the city is added in database. this.getAllCities() gets the list of old cities try it like this.

```
 PostData(addNewForm: NgForm) {
        var object = {
            "city_name": addNewForm.value.city_name,
            "state_id": addNewForm.value.state_id
        }
        this.service.addCity(object).subscribe(
          (data)=> {
                this.modalRef.hide();
                this.getAllCities();
            }
        ); 
    }
```